# Printing oracle sql Statement output in java eclipse console not working

Tags: java, sql, oracle, console

I have a problem. I would like to implement a SQL Statement, into java and print it out in the console. When I do so, it gives me the wrong line or just a number:

So my Java code is this:

```
ConnectTodb daba = new ConnectTodb("password");
daba.connect();
System.out.println(db.getStatement().executeUpdate("SELECT * FROM (select entry, row_number() over(order by entrie_date desc) rn from entry) where rn = 1"));
```

When I perform this, it just prints the number 0 or sometimes 1. That makes no sense because the numbers in my database are different ones (like 8800 or 110200.23).

When I perform the same command `(SELECT * FROM (select entry, row_number() over(order by entrie_date desc) rn from entry) where rn = 1)` in my oracle sql Developer, it gives me the right number...

Comment: Look at the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))
*Returns:
    either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing*
You need [this approach](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/22-resultset-to-tablemodel)

Comment: I don't get it. It says that executeUpdate is only for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE. I am using SELECT so i changed it to executeQuery. But now i have another output (that also is not right): oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@7c8c9a05

Comment: You can handle that ```ResultSet```  using the code at the second link I posted

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the [Oracle JDBC Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) to learn how to use the JDBC API.